# How would I fix this patch so that the hardwood looks consistent?

Tags: repair, floor, hardwood

Going to need some guidance on how I could replace this patch so that the hardwood goes throughout

[image: this is floor]

Comment: Would be a nice place to put a dresser/cabinet or a sofa/couch/chair.

Comment: Sometimes you can get the donor wood out of a closet where an obvious patch doesn't look as apparent.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to find a material that is close to what you have now and use that in the patch.  How you'd go about that depends on the install type of hard wood.  I can't tell if this is face nail, tongue nail with tongue and grove or glue down.

Another option would be to replace the outside boards in a room with a different color but take them up carefully and use them in the patch area.  Accent patterns are commonly used in ornate hardwood flooring.  One example is french knot.

I've had luck with getting matching flooring in heritage houses by calling places that sell salvaged materials.  If you know the dimensions of the pieces you can call around.  Habitat for Humanity often runs salvage stores.  The other option is driving around your neighborhood and taking note of houses that are similar in age to yours and looking for houses that are ready for tear down and then trying to get in to salvage flooring yourself.

Do you know what type of wood it is and the approximate date?

How much time and money do you want to budget to the project?  It is often easier and sometimes a lot nicer to just install LVP overtop and get a modern floor that is easier to clean, looks great and can be water proof.  If you have the time, money, energy and love the current look then restoration is certainly possible.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think I am going with a floating floor,

Comment: are French knots  difficult to make?

Comment: French knot is just inlay....   I wouldn't say difficult.  A compass rose inlay on the other hand I would consider difficult.

Comment: Getting a professional in to replace _AND_ refinish just this little section of wood to match the rest of the floor could cost as much as covering the whole thing with LVP. _WARNING Opinion:_ The money spent on patching would be far better than money spent of fake flooring - this is a beautiful looking floor and doesn't deserve to be hidden from the world.

Comment: Alternatively, patch the floor, then refinish the _whole_ floor which could be DIY.

Answer (score 1):

to look consistent the surfaces need to be blended smoothly.

will require adding filler and/or sanding down high spots (it's unclear in the photo) as this is a baseboard and subject to occasional impacts I would recommend a durable filler like bondo. rather than some sort of plaster.